# Puppeteer - Pdf options: Invalid parameters handle: string value expected

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, nest

I want to convert html to pdf so I am using puppeteer, and when I execute code, I get error on pdf options
ProtocolError: Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected.
So I am using puppeteer v13.0.0, node: v14.18.1, macos m1 chip
I checked out open issues, which tells about downgrade but didn't worked

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.18.1 As development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev chromium
RUN apt-get install -y \
    fonts-liberation \
    gconf-service \
    libappindicator1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgbm-dev \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libpng-dev \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    xdg-utils
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium
RUN npm install --only=development
RUN npm i puppeteer
RUN chmod -R o+rwx node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
COPY . .
RUN npm install rimraf
RUN npm run build
FROM node:14.2.0 as production
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

Code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium",
        args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"],
      });

      // create a new page(opening a new tab with new page)
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      // set html inside page
      await page.setContent(html);

      // provide some options(eg: width, height) to page
      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf(options);
      console.log("PDF buffer is", pdfBuffer);

      // clear out our Puppeteer instance to free memory
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
      
      return pdfBuffer;
```

Options:

```
{
        path: "print.pdf",
        height: "8.3in",
        width: "11.7in",
        margin: {
          top: "0.1in",
          right: "0.5in",
          bottom: "0.1in",
          left: "0.5in",
        },
      }
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "file-upload",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.2.0",
    "npm": "6.13.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0 --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.36.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.4.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.6",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/helmet": "0.0.47",
    "@types/uuid": "^7.0.5",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1006.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "canvas": "^2.8.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.5.5",
    "helmet": "^3.23.3",
    "html-pdf": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemin": "^7.0.1",
    "imagemin-gm": "^2.0.2",
    "imagemin-webp": "^5.1.0",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.0",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.72",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "puppeteer": "^13.0.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^13.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.12",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.38",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "ws": "^8.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/types": "^3.36.0",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.3.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.18",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.17.22",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/pg": "^7.14.11",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^5.4.4",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/ws": "^8.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^7.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.11.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "src/main.ts",
      ".spec.ts",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      "tests/(.*)": "<rootDir>/__tests__/$1"
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ProtocolError: Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected

    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:226:24

    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

    at CDPSession.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:222:16)

    at Readable.read [as _read] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/helper.js:276:43)

    at Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:465:10)

    at createAsyncIterator (internal/streams/readable.js:1131:54)

    at createAsyncIterator.next (<anonymous>)

    at Object.getReadableAsBuffer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/helper.js:247:22)

    at async Page.pdf (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:2104:16)

    at async PdfGenerationService.createPdf (/usr/src/app/dist/pdf-generation/pdf-generation.service.js:21:31)

    at async EmailService.createPoChallan (/usr/src/app/dist/email/email.service.js:174:30)

    at async EmailService.createPurchaseOrderMail (/usr/src/app/dist/email/email.service.js:193:55)

    at async ErpService.handleStocks (/usr/src/app/dist/erp/erp.service.js:62:17)

    at async ErpController.inventoryUpdate (/usr/src/app/dist/erp/erp.controller.js:29:9)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may help if you post your `package.json` file

Comment: hey @AnthumChris, I have added package.json file.